# Comparing window titles that share a common structure but are not exactly the same in Windows OS

Tags: java, string, windows-7, jna

I am currently working on a project, in Java, that deals with interruptions. My aim is to learn when it is a good time to interrupt the user. At the moment my current method is to have a list of windows that should not be interrupted and compare that to the window that is in focus every 3 seconds and then use keyboard hooks to detect if they are typing.

However, I have come across the issue that Microsoft Word and many other programs don't have fixed window titles. If a user wants to add Microsoft Word to the don't interrupt list then it will just add the file name that is currently being worked on rather than something that can be used to uniquely identify Microsoft Windows. Another example is twitter, if the user adds `twitter` to the list then it wont consider `(15) twitter` to be equivalent.

Is there any alternative method that can be used to detect which program the window title belongs to or a string searching method that may be ideal for this problem?

I am also open to entirely new methods on how this could be done.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `stringThatContainsWindowName.indexOf(stringfromDontInterruptList)>0` do the job?

Comment: indexOf returns the zero-based position of the string it's passed (stringFromDontInterruptList in this case) inside of the string it's called on (stringThatContainsWindowName), or -1 if it is not found. In your example, it would return something like 5, hence the comparison at the end. So, in short, if stringFromDontInterruptList is within stringThatContainsWindowName, it will return a number 0 or greater. Keep in mind this would be case-sensitive, so you might want to do toLowerCase or something like that on both strings.

Comment: `stringThatContainsWindowName.contains(stringFromDontInterruptList)` is a boolean that replaces the `indexOf` expression and makes it clearer what you are doing. Another suggestion would be to build a regular expression around a key phrase in the name and apply it.  Per @MattSieker's note about case, you could apply the regex in a case insensitive fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better answer than using the window title is to get the actual process id and save that in a list of processes not to be interrupted. That way you won't have to worry about the name changing.

Something like what is done here should do the trick: http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid

Another way to get the PID that is less optimal:

If you can't figure out that example... another option to get the PID is the following:

```
String line = "";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe -v");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); // this should print out process names with PID

}
```

Comment: Added a different way to get the pid to the answer but you should probably be using JNA.